# how to create Java gui application like this in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I am creating a Java desktop application where the user will enter his name and age and press next, like given below in image 1.

[image]

And the action would perform would be like given in the image below in image 2.

[image]

I went through all tutorials on the Netbeans site, but still I was not able find any solution. I want to build this application like what we see when we install some application on Windows, we select some option and press next and a new window will appear with the result or more options. Please somebody help me with step by step instruction.

Comment: Read [Trail: Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing (The Java™ Tutorials)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).

Comment: Asking for a step by step instruction on how to build a GUI app seems overly broad. Read, repeat tutorials, and if you get stuck, ask specific questions. Then modify your code and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll get as much out of "step by step" instructions as you will going through the tutorials and learning not only how to do what you're desire, but the whys and hows of what you're doing.  That being said, you will want to go through several of the [Java Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) to learn how to do this including

- the [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to see how to swap JComponents in a GUI.
- The [JTextField tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) to see how to interact with JTextFields
- The [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) tutorial to see how to interact with JButtons and how to respond to their presses.

Much of learning to code means independent study and much trial and error. So start experimenting and have fun doing so!

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer says, the CardLayout is a one way of doing this. However, in my case, I find that cardlayout is bit difficult for me. So, what I do is, creating JavaBeans, which extends JPanel, in this case. So you can add them to the main view and dispose/replace with another JavaBean, making different "Next" views. This way will help you to seperate your code into several classes, making the code simple too.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/swing/wizard/) contains more or less a step-by-step tutorial on how to create a wizard in Swing. But before you start with that article make sure you have some basic Swing knowledge or that article will be complete Gibberish

Comment: The link is no longer working. The new URL at Oracle is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/wizard-136789.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use installation wizard creator tool for make a setup of your java application

for examaple you can use 
"Setup Factory" tool for create a install exe of your application

it make a installer like that which you in your quetion